# How to horizontally scroll through columns in materialize css

Tags: css, horizontal-scrolling, materialize

I am using materialize css, even if I add lot of columns, they adjusts themselves according to the size of the page. I want to make them horizontally scrollable. How to make it scrollable? Here is my table code:

```
<table class="striped centered responsive-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>USN</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Department</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Student's Phone</th>
        <th>Parent's Phone</th>
        <th>Student's Email</th>
        <th>Parent's Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
  <?php 
  $result=$db->query($semqy);
  $i=0;
  while($semdata=$result->fetch_assoc())
  {
      echo "<tr><td>
      <input type='checkbox' id='chkbx$i' name='chkbx$i'/>
      <label for='chkbx$i'></label>
      </td><td>".$semdata['USN']."</td><td>".$semdata['Name']."</td><td>".$semdata['Dept']."</td><td>".$semdata['Address']."</td><td>".$semdata['Sphone']."</td><td>".$semdata['Pphone']."</td><td>".$semdata['Semail']."</td><td>".$semdata['Pemail']."</td></tr>";
      $i++;
  }
  ?>
  <tr><td>Send Email</td></tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Student</td><td>
  <input type="checkbox" id="schkbx" name="schkbx"/><label for="schkbx"></label></td>
  <td>Parent</td><td><input type="checkbox" id="pchkbx" name="pchkbx"/><label for="pchkbx"></label></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Without seeing any code its impossible to say, but start by with `overflow-x: auto"

Comment: Your question is about css, but you added php code. Why?

Comment: Actually, I uploaded the html part of my code which contains some php and also the css classes. In materialize css it is difficult to find the exact css code thats why.

Answer (score 1):

A proposed way to go around this is to wrap your table within a  who's function is going to be a container and an overflow window.

```
<div class='table-wrapper'>
    <!-- Table Content goes here -->
</div>
```

With table wrapper in place, you can hide the exceeding content in any overflow you wish. You can check the overflow properties and what they do here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow?v=example

For your need, since it's horizontal, we'd want to use the property **overflow-x** and to *force* a scroll bar to the division, we would add **scroll** to it.

Of course, you will have to define the max-width of your wrapper div to the desired measure. Additionnaly, you will ahve to force a size on your table cell to make them take the appropriate space you desire.

Also, very importantly, you will need to set the properties of your table as such:

```
#tableName {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

This will prevent your table from resizing with the container size.

You can look at an example here:

https://codepen.io/DrSandwich/pen/ZKyvoP

Comment: Thanks! working as expected, but the text from last 2 columns (students email and parents email) are overlapping...any solutions?

Comment: Have you maybe tried to check if you need to adjust the width of the content for each table cell?

Don't forget that in the end of the day, the table will act as a table and if your content bleeds out, it will overlap with the rest. I do believe you can make a few adjustement to tweak it :)

Comment: I tried, actually to separate it I have to use a lot of spacing (width). But why just the last one's are overlapping and not other columns?